# Apache Storm Junit test case for bolt

Tags: java, junit, apache-storm

I have written a bolt and a topology. Now I need to do a Junit test case. My actual input is a Json and in my bolt I have written code to store this in MySQL. Now I need to test my logic which I have written in `execute()` method. So how to create a object for the tuple in the test case or is there any other way to do this. I have attached the code of my `execute()` method.

```
public void execute(Tuple input, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
    int size = input.getFields().size();
    Fields fields = input.getFields();
    if (size == 1) {
        logger.info("PostbackToRDSBolt execute method starts");
        try {
                eventJson = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON((String) input.getValueByField(fields.get(0)));
                address = (String) input.getValueByField(fields.get(0));
                Id = (String) eventJson.get("Id");
                click = (String) eventJson.get("click");
                time = (String) eventJson.get("time");
                uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                type = "post";
                //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        dBUrl, username,
                        password);
                stmt = con.createStatement();
                stmt.execute("INSERT INTO " + tableName
                        + "(id,data,type,txnid,groupname,time)values('" + uuid
                        + "','" + address + "'," + "'" + type + "','"
                        + Id + "','" + click + "','" + time
                        + "')");
                logger.info("inserted successfully in mysql");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                logger.info("" + e1);
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Best practice is to encapsulate your logic into a service class to ease unit tests instead of testing directly your bolt. You can then create integration tests using a LocalCluster instance.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do JUnit testing, one approach would be to use Mockito library:

For example:

```
@Test
public void testExecute() {
    Tuple t = mock(Tuple.class);
    when(t.getFields()).thenReturn(new Fields("myAttribute"));
    when(t.getValueByField("myAttribute").thenReturn("my json string to be tested");

    MyBolt b = new MyBolt();
    b.execute(t, mock(BasicOutputCollector.class));

    // put your assertions here
}
```

For this to work, you should change your code in `execute()` a little bit. From

```
int size = input.getFields().size();
Fields fields = input.getFields();
```

to

```
Fields fields = input.getFields();
int size = fields.size();
```

Otherwise, `input.getFields()` is called twice but the test only specified a single return value for this method, and thus, the second call will return `null`. (As an alternative, you can also mock both calls to `getFields()`.)

If you don't want to mock everything you can also instantiate `TupleImpl` objects (`Tuple t = new TupleImpl(...)`) and pass them to `execute()` in your test.